# How to change caret style of a fxruby text field?

Tags: ruby, fxruby

I am building a small IDE with [fxruby](http://www.fxruby.org/).

The default caret of FXTextField is a little bit ugly (a big tall thin 'I'), I hope I could change the caret style but can't find any help after several hours of googling.

Any hint?